# How to get random records in Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm currently using this method:

```
.OrderBy(s => Guid.NewGuid())
.Take(10)
...
```

But then I noticed a warning in my logs:

```
The LINQ expression 'orderby NewGuid() asc' could not be
translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

I'm using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 1.1.1

Comment: Do you want to retrieve random records or `.OrderBy()` randomly?

Comment: `Guid.NewGuid()` creates a new random guid every time its called. I believe that query would give you randomly selected 10 records. The warning showing that it cannot translate the order by to SQL. To allow translation, first there should be equivalent method available on your database & your EF provider should have translator to do the conversion. In EFCore.SqlServer it translate `Guid.NewGuid()` to `NEWID` on SQL server.
Try filing an issue on their GitHub repo.

Comment: @Smit I forked the library and created a translator for `Guid.NewGuid`, only to realize `UUID()` in MySQL will give the same value -- per query at least. Then I turned into MySQL's `rand()` but I encountered a problem and skipped the task at the moment.

Comment: @Smit - `Guid.NewGuid()` generates a unique guid every time it is called. There is no guarantee that it will be random at all.

Comment: @Enigmativity huh??

Comment: @Luke - What do you mean "huh??"?